# How to get xml data on user selection?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have these four radio button, I am passing data from a XML file into them.  Once the user clicks the button, I want to capture it in a variable.

```
$("<p><input name='choice' type='radio'>"+choice1+"</p>").appendTo(choice1Div);
$(choice1Div).click(function() {
var isChecked = ($('input[value=choice]:checked').val());
```

But I am getting an error :/  What am I doing wrong?  I have to design a multiple choice quiz.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: your selector is wrong $("<p><input name='choice' type='radio'>"+choice1+"</p>")  it should be $("#choice1Div").appendTo(<p><input name='choice' type='radio'>"+choice1+"</p>);

Comment: getting an unexpected < token warning.

Comment: missing  quotes around html .  Try this $("#choice1Div").appendTo("<p><input name='choice' type='radio'>"+choice1+"</p>'); @LandmineSalesman

Comment: Appreciate the help but it didn't work.  I tried a few other things as well.  Oh well!